# Sorry, I wasn't able to send a letter (earlier or in earlier time)

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is there a difference in meaning between writing "in earlier time" and "earlier", for example

> I wasn't able to send you an email (**earlier \ in earlier time**).

Comment: 'In earlier time' isn't a correct/commonly used expression in any context I can think of.

Comment: "In earlier time" is not idiomatic.   Where have you heard this phrase?  It's possible to say *"**at** an earlier time"* but not in this context.

Comment: @Andrew *At an earlier time* would work quite well in this context.

Comment: @JasonBassford  You'll have to give me an example.  Any way I try to fit it in, it sounds forced.

Comment: @Andrew The one you alluded to sounds fine to me: *I wasn't able to send you email at an earlier time.* It's just a bit more formal than the alternative.

Comment: I didn't think that the problem is in the preposition.

The Guardian: However, BBC bosses may be reluctant to show the ceremony **at an earlier time** as it would mean bumping a substantially more popular show such as Call the Midwife from a peak Sunday early evening time slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I used the wrong preposition. Check the following example which is extracted from The Guardian:

> However, BBC bosses may be reluctant to show the ceremony ***at* an
>   earlier time** as it would mean bumping a substantially more popular
>   show such as Call the Midwife from a peak Sunday early evening time
>   slot.